# Can't call data from second string

Tags: java

I have looked through some of the other questions asking about a similar issue, but I am trying to call the double 'thirdPrice' from calculationMethod() to main(). The purpose of this program is to request data in main(), pass some of the info to calculationMethod() and then return that data back to main() for final output. I am using DrJava, here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Imports input device
public class CraftPricing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in); //Sets up input device
        String productName; //Used for naming product
        double costMaterials, hoursWorked; //Gives variables decimal format
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the product "); //Enter product name
        productName = inputDevice.nextLine(); //Passes variable for calculation
        System.out.println("Enter the cost of materials prior to discount "); //Enter cost of materials
        costMaterials = inputDevice.nextDouble(); //Passes variable for calculation
        System.out.println("Enter the number of hours worked "); //Enter hours worked
        hoursWorked = inputDevice.nextDouble(); //Passes variable for calculation
        System.out.printf("The cost of " + productName + " is %.2f\n" , thirdPrice);
        //Output product name and cost
    }
    public static void calculationMethod() //Method used to calcualte price
    {
        double itemDiscount = 0.75; //Gives decimal format to variable
        double payRate = 14.00; //Gives decimal format to variable
        double shipHandle = 6.00; //Gives decimal format to variable
        double firstPrice = payRate * 7; //Calculates fisr portion of equation
        double secondPrice = 7 + firstPrice; //Calculates second portion of equation
        final double thirdPrice = itemDiscount * secondPrice + shipHandle;
        //Calculates final portion of equation
        return thirdPrice; //Returns double to main() for output
    }
}
```

The errors I receive when trying to compile are as follows:

2 errors found:
File: C:\Users\unkno\DrJava\Java\CraftPricing.java  [line: 18]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable thirdPrice
  location: class CraftPricing
File: C:\Users\unkno\DrJava\Java\CraftPricing.java  [line: 28]
Error: incompatible types: unexpected return value

Comment: You can't return from a void method

Comment: `thirdPrice` is not defined and you're attempting to use it within the `main` method.

Comment: Do you understand what `void` means, or are you just blindly typing whatever sounds familiar into your code without understanding what it means and does?

Comment: Still very new to coding period. Went back to my textbook and read about 'void'. Now I see why it didn't do anything when I had it in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a variable at all?

Call the method.

```
System.out.printf("The cost of %s is %.2f\n" , productName, calculationMethod());
```

Or learn about variable scope.

And also fix the return type.

```
public static double calculationMethod()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I have been flipping through my textbook and looking at other resources with no head way at all.

Comment: Well now I have a new issue, I forgot that I had changed some variables to exact numbers in order to make some errors go away.

Comment: Feel free to create a new post if you're unable to fix them. Don't ask new questions in the comments unless it's about this answer